# Forward and back native buttons in UIWebview iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, uiwebview

Inside the Twitter iPhone app, if you click on a link it pushes in a WebView.

Ive gotten this far, but I can't find the correct identifier for the forward and backward buttons like at the bottom left of the image below. Are they native? or are they just images they have created themselves?

[image: web view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the list of `UIBarButtonItems` from the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarButtonItem), those items you desire need to be custom images a they are not provided in the current SDK.

Answer (score 13):

You might want to have a look at a drop-in inline web view controller I did: [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController). It should save you a fair bit of coding :)

Comment: ta, grabbed the images from you